# Grouping of list of list for elments of inner list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of list like:

```
List = [['Server1','Server2','Server4','Server6','EnvName1','become_a'],
        ['Server2','Server3','Server1','Server5','EnvName2','become_a'],
        ['Server4','Server3','Server7','Server6','EnvName3','become_b'],
        ['Server5','Server1','Server2','Server3','EnvName4','become_a'],
        ['Server4','Server2','Server1','Server7','EnvName5','become_b']]
```

What my list of list contains is name of the server, Environment on which it is running and become account used to do ssh on them, I want to run some shell scripts on them but i don't want to do redundant ssh connections on them for different environments. So i thought to group them. My grouping should be like all the EnvNames having same server and become account should be group in a list so that i do ssh on that server only once, If for two EnvNames server is same but the become account is different then i want them to be in a separate list.

My final list should look something like this:

```
Final_List = [['Server1','EnvName1,EnvName2,EnvName4','become_a'],
              ['Server1','Envname5','become_b'],
              ['Server2','EnvName1,Envname2','become_a'],
              ['Server2','EnvName5','become_b'],
              ['Server3','EnvName2,EnvName4','become_a'],
              ['Server3','EnvName3','become_b'],
              ['Server4','EnvName1','become_a'],
              ['Server4','EnvName3,EnvName5','become_b'],
              ['Server5','EnvName5','become_a'],
              ['Server6','EnvName1','become_a'],
              ['Server6','EnvName3','become_b'],
              ['Server7','EnvName3,EnvName5','become_b']]
```

I tried to group them but it went horribly wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to group entries on server and account name.

Use a dictionary to do the grouping, keyed on a tuple:

```
grouped = {}
for entry in List:
    env, account = entry[-2:]
    for server in entry[:-2]:
        key = server, account
        grouped.setdefault(key, []).append(env)
```

Once grouped you can list these for your final output:

```
Final_List = [[server] + environments + [account]
              for (server, account), environments in sorted(grouped.items())]
```

This produces *separate entries* for the environment strings. You can put these into one string with:

```
Final_List = [[server, ','.join(environments), account]
              for (server, account), environments in sorted(grouped.items())]
```

Demo:

```
>>> List = [['Server1','Server2','Server4','Server6','EnvName1','become_a'],
...         ['Server2','Server3','Server1','Server5','EnvName2','become_a'],
...         ['Server4','Server3','Server7','Server6','EnvName3','become_b'],
...         ['Server5','Server1','Server2','Server3','EnvName4','become_a'],
...         ['Server4','Server2','Server1','Server7','EnvName5','become_b']]
>>> grouped = {}
>>> for entry in List:
...     env, account = entry[-2:]
...     for server in entry[:-2]:
...         key = server, account
...         grouped.setdefault(key, []).append(env)
... 
>>> [[server] + environments + [account]
...               for (server, account), environments in sorted(grouped.items())]
[['Server1', 'EnvName1', 'EnvName2', 'EnvName4', 'become_a'],
 ['Server1', 'EnvName5', 'become_b'],
 ['Server2', 'EnvName1', 'EnvName2', 'EnvName4', 'become_a'],
 ['Server2', 'EnvName5', 'become_b'],
 ['Server3', 'EnvName2', 'EnvName4', 'become_a'],
 ['Server3', 'EnvName3', 'become_b'],
 ['Server4', 'EnvName1', 'become_a'],
 ['Server4', 'EnvName3', 'EnvName5', 'become_b'],
 ['Server5', 'EnvName2', 'EnvName4', 'become_a'],
 ['Server6', 'EnvName1', 'become_a'],
 ['Server6', 'EnvName3', 'become_b'],
 ['Server7', 'EnvName3', 'EnvName5', 'become_b']]
>>> [[server, ','.join(environments), account]
...               for (server, account), environments in sorted(grouped.items())]
[['Server1', 'EnvName1,EnvName2,EnvName4', 'become_a'],
 ['Server1', 'EnvName5', 'become_b'],
 ['Server2', 'EnvName1,EnvName2,EnvName4', 'become_a'], 
 ['Server2', 'EnvName5', 'become_b'],
 ['Server3', 'EnvName2,EnvName4', 'become_a'],
 ['Server3', 'EnvName3', 'become_b'],
 ['Server4', 'EnvName1', 'become_a'],
 ['Server4', 'EnvName3,EnvName5', 'become_b'],
 ['Server5', 'EnvName2,EnvName4', 'become_a'],
 ['Server6', 'EnvName1', 'become_a'],
 ['Server6', 'EnvName3', 'become_b'],
 ['Server7', 'EnvName3,EnvName5', 'become_b']]
```

Comment: Not sure if the OP necessarily wants it but `'EnvName1,EnvName2,EnvName4'` etc.. are  grouped into  single strings

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: added an option to join the names too.